# IE thumbnail pixelation when high resolution image is set to small size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox

> Current version of plugin does not support fixing pixelation issue for
> images with transparent background. But it shows the way how to fix it
> using canvas. Adding WebGL functionality will make it faster and enable handling images
> with transparent background.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('img.first').bicubicImgInterpolation({
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous' //for demo purpose
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/sukhoi1/Crossbrowser-Bicubic-Image-Interpolation/master/bicubicInterpolation.js"></script>

Handled by <b>Bicubic Image Interpolation</b> plugin:<br>
<img id="someId" class="first" width="200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Text_Line_Length.png/800px-Text_Line_Length.png"><br>

IE9 to IE11 and Edge <b>pixelated thumbnail</b>:<br> 
<img class="second" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Text_Line_Length.png/800px-Text_Line_Length.png" width="200" alt=""><br><br>
```

I have found a plugin, which seems to solve pixelation issue for all versions of IE and Edge browsers, it is called "Crossbrowser-Bicubic-Image-Interpolation".

Here is a code snippet which may solve the issue for many people using jQuery.

Detailed [reference](https://github.com/sukhoi1/Crossbrowser-Bicubic-Image-Interpolation/wiki) to the problem on GitHub.

Comment: I'm voting to have this question migrated to Meta StackOverflow, but in the meantime do you have a link to the question where you originally posted your answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945363/image-scaling-causes-poor-quality-in-firefox-internet-explorer-but-not-chrome

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110987/images-in-ie-are-pixelated

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108615/high-resolution-image-ie-browser-rendering

Comment: Your answers were pretty much identical, link-only content with no stand-alone value. This is considered spam and is why they were removed.

Comment: But the questions are also identical, they are all about the same thing :)

Comment: Then they should be closed as duplicates of each other. If you're copy-pasting an answer, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: This solves my problem with images in Explorer